# Как программно можно менять виртуальные рабочие столы в Win10(на C#)

Tags: c#

```
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("Shell32.dll")]
    private static extern int SHChangeNotify(int eventId, int flags, IntPtr item1, IntPtr item2);
```

Comment: код это пример обновления рабочего стола(f5)

Comment: Вот пример по теме: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31801402/276994 (но он не отвечает на ваш вопрос)